# Dropdown Button-html/bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

My dropdown button code doesn't seem to work at all. Can someone help me out in this?

Code-

```
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a
            class="nav-link dropdown-toggle"
            href="#"
            id="navbarDropdown"
            role="button"
            data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
            aria-expanded="false"
          >
          Topics
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Technology</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Web Developnment</a></li>
            <li><hr class="dropdown-divider" /></li>
            <li>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Support</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Write For Us</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
```

Comment: Did you include the bootstrap.js script?

Comment: Yes i included all the necessary links in the script.

Answer (score 0):

Should be `<a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-fQybjgWLrvvRgtW6bFlB7jaZrFsaBXjsOMm/tB9LTS58ONXgqbR9W8oWht/amnpF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<li class="nav-item dropdown">
  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    Topics
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Technology</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Web Developnment</a></li>
    <li>
      <hr class="dropdown-divider" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Support</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Write For Us</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```